# Is there a way to change a few lines of code so all the ternary expression would follow?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have following code to construct a view with many `Text()` that all follow the same `foregroundColor` statement:

```
struct myView: View {
    @Binding var darkMode: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Text(...)
            .foregroundColor(darkMode ? Color.white : Color.gray)
        ...
        Text(...)
            .foregroundColor(darkMode ? Color.white : Color.gray)
        ...
        Text(...)
            .foregroundColor(darkMode ? Color.white : Color.gray)
        ...
        Text(...)
            .foregroundColor(darkMode ? Color.white : Color.gray)
        ...
        // more Text() using the same statement of .foregroundColor
        ...
    }
}
```

There is a problem for me here. For example, if I want to change using `Color.blue` for `darkMode`, I have to change all the `.foregroundColor()` of `Text()` in this view. There are maybe 20-30 places, and maybe I would miss one.

Is there a way to change a few lines of "centralized" code so all the `Text().foregroundColor()` would follow?

PS. The example in my question is a simplified one. I have other views other than `Text()` that use `darkMode` to decide colors. Besides, there are other color combinations for different views based on `darkMode`. Therefore, I am looking for other solution than a custom view. Thanks.

My intuitive way to achieve this is to have a variable to hold the value, something like this:

`var myColor = darkMode ? Color.white : Color.gray`

but this gives compiler error if I put it in the struct definition. The question I asked here is to try finding some workaround for this.

Comment: Make a custom `Text` view specific for your app.

Comment: No a `View` I added an answer below

Comment: You should use a colour asset in your asset catalogue to store these colours. If you provide a dark and light mode variant, the system will automatically pick between them, for you.

Comment: @Alexander In UIKit it is also possible to form a UIColor that behaves that way programmatically. I don't know about SwiftUI colors.

Answer (score 0):

The `foregroundColor` modifier is applied to the entire tree of the view it's used on. You can wrap all your Text elements in a Group and add the `foregroundColor` to the Group.

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @Binding var darkMode: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            Text(...)
            Text(...)
            ...
        }
        .foregroundColor(darkMode ? Color.white : Color.gray)
    }
}
```

It doesn't have to be a `Group`. It could be a `VStack`, a custom view, or any sort of view. If you want to apply the foreground color to your whole app, you can add `foregroundColor` to your `App`'s root view:

```swift
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                ...
            }
            .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.white : Color.gray)
        }
    }
}
```